# Replacing soldered pins with FFC socket

Tags: pins, socket

I have this PCB where 13 cable pins used to be soldered to. I'd like to replace that with a standard FFC connector socket. Is this possible given the pattern shown in the image?

[image]

Comment: I don't see why not... but it means what you mean by replacement. Doing some hand soldering to mount a connector there wouldn't be too hard (depending on how the connector pads look of course), but doing the same with a placement machine in production is another story.

Comment: Looking for a simple solution I could implement myself I was wondering what type of connector could easily be mounted.

Comment: What's the pitch?

Comment: the pitch is 1.25 mm

Comment: Then something along the lines of this perhaps? https://www.jst-mfg.com/product/detail_e.php?series=105. Check JST and Molex. They'll have both crimp and IDC versions.

Comment: Thanks, I'm looking at this. Not being familiar with it I' m wondering why it doesn't mention the number of pins.

Comment: They are typically available with a variable amount of pins, this particular one can be ordered with anything from 2 to 15. Check the datasheet for possible part numbers.

Comment: That's what they call circuits. So I could insert a 13-pin FFC into a 13-circuit crimp style connector. What I still don't see is how it would be mounted in relation to my board picture.